# Removing element node from xml file based on having specific attribute using DOM

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have the following xml file structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data Calls="1" Method="setDescription(java.lang.String) void" Class="Symptom" Package="emrservicedesign" Base_Time_.seconds.="0.000004"/>
<data Invoked_by="1" Method="testSetDescription() void" Class="SymptomTest"/>
<data Calls="4" Method="setDescription(java.lang.String) void" Class="Symptom" Package="emrservicedesign" Base_Time_.seconds.="0.000004"/>
</View>
```

what am trying to do is to remove all element nodes that have "Invoked_by" as attribute, so the the result of the above xml file should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data Calls="1" Method="setDescription(java.lang.String) void" Class="Symptom" Package="emrservicedesign" Base_Time_.seconds.="0.000004"/>
<data Calls="4" Method="setDescription(java.lang.String) void" Class="Symptom" Package="emrservicedesign" Base_Time_.seconds.="0.000004"/> 
</View>
```

This is the code I have written

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("data");     
for (int i = 1; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
{Node node = nodes.item(i); 
Element e = (Element) node;
if (e.hasAttribute("Invoked_by")){ nodes.item(i).removeChild(node);}
```

**This is the error**

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
```

I appreciate if Any body can help

Comment: I wrote this code but it gives me an error,                     NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("data");                for (int i = 1; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Node node = nodes.item(i);
Element e = (Element) node;                                        if (e.hasAttribute("Invoked_by")){
nodes.item(i).removeChild((Node) e);
                          }

Comment: Can you put your code in the original question (hit edit under the question) and include the error you get?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to remove `node` from `nodes.item(i)` which is `node` itself? Isn't `node.getParentNode().removeChild(node)` more likely correct?

Answer (score 0):

as Invoked_by is not the attribute of every node so before applying the remove method of XML on the Invoked_by attribute first check for the availability of the attribute in every node.